# What are Techniques for Ring finger and Pinky Finger

Tags: guitar, technique, legato

What are some techniques that you think i can use for the ring finger and pinky finger in sync? Im feeling difficulty when using the ring and pinky for hammering.. Im an intermediate guitar player.. Im currently learning Legato for Always with me always with you..

Answer (score 1):

Start at fret 5, top string. hammer on there with index, then 6 with middle, 7 with ring and 8 with pinky. If you have a problem with pinky by itself, then use ring as well, one fret below. Then alternate frets 5,7,6,8, and other combinations.

Soon after, practise pull-offs as well, same ideas, adding 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6, but use your fingers in turn, only keep index on 5. Keep it slow and smooth (legato), and make every note the same volume and tempo. Then, you've guessed it, 5 7 5 7 5 7 etc. At no point do you need to use the hand with a pick in it.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean fingers 3 and 4 (your left hand.) Many players have their hand at the diagonal to the edge of the fingerboard which makes using finger 4 almost impossible. Keep the palm parallel to it and keep your fingertips upright with fingers curved. Then practice SLOWLY, and lots.